# Udev : renaming my network interface

Tags: linux, rhel, udev

I just installed *RHEL 6.3* on a Dell 1950 server.
This server as two GBit ports, Gb0 and Gb1.

For some obscure reason, `udev` chose to name *Gb0* `eth1` and *Gb1* `eth0`.
This is definitly not a good find for me and just gives confusion.

So I modified the configuration in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`:

```
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x164c (bnx2)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", \
  ATTR{address}=="00:20:19:52:d3:c0",           \
  ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# PCI device 0x14e4:0x164c (bnx2)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", \
  ATTR{address}=="00:20:19:52:d3:be",           \
  ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

I just changed the "NAME" field on the file in order to reflect what I want.
I rebooted the server and it didn't worked.

In the `dmesg` log I can read the following :

```
udev: renamed network interface eth1 to rename5
udev: renamed network interface eth0 to eth1
udev: renamed network interface rename5 to eth0
```

Any idea on what is wrong here?
Why is `udev` switching like this? I have another similar server, where I do not have this issue.

Comment: so what is the assignment now? still Gb0==eth1 & Gb1==eth0?

Comment: once check `grep -R 'rename5' /etc/udev/rules.d/` because in logs why it is showing `rename5` is any other rule for the same ?

Comment: I've done similar thing for network interfaces and it shows just like that in the log (if you follow the logic in it, it just assigns a bogus name to original eth1 so that it can rename original eth0 to eth1). So according to the log everything should be ok. Are you sure the names are not ok yet?

Comment: The assignment is still wrong : Gb0==eth1 & Gb1==eth0. Its like the changes I made in the file are not applied. I don't have any trace of rename5 in /etc/udev/rules.d/. What I understand is when kernel boot eth0 and eth1 are boot but udev switch them. eth0 => eth1 and eth1 => eth0

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am struggling with this problem too. On normal boot, I end up with p1p1 and p1p2. But since I have plugged a network cable on p1p2, on some boot (not all, which is weird), I end up with p1p1 and rename3!?!? Udev is renaming eth1 to rename3 instead of p1p2 for whatever reason. This of course break the network i/f configuration and firewall X-( Not that I am on Ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried using [iftab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/iftab) and [ifrename](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifrename)? I mean honestly, udev is overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my case, the issue is coming from the fact that the mac address for each interface was set in three files :

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
```

We need consistency between ifcfg file and net.rules for the mac address.

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig` is on redhat/centos linux.  On Ubuntu those files would be under `/etc/network/if-up.d`

Answer (score 11):

While this is rather late, I fixed my issue by removing the

```
KERNEL="eth*",
```

part of the rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file. This works because, once UDEV has renamed the device to "rename*", this part will stop the rule matching. So, removing it allows the correct name to be assigned to the correct device regardless of what UDEV has called it in the meantime.

Comment: This solved it for me also on ubuntu 14.04. Exactly the same behaviour as the OP (except that the rename was to pXpY).

Comment: Just fixing the mac address worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve this by simply deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and rebooting.

Answer (score 3):

It also might happen because eth0, eth1, wlan0, wlan1 etc. are standard kernel names (in case of non-persistent scheme naming). In udev documentation it's said:

> NAME
>
> The name to use for a network interface. See systemd.link(5) for a higher-level mechanism for setting the interface name. The name of a device node **cannot be changed** by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.

So never use eth*, wlan* etc. names for udev rules.

Comment: Not certain about **cannot be changed** but indeed `NAME=ethN` does not work if `ethN` already exists. So instead `NAME=tobe_ethN` in udev rules, then `rename tobe_ethN=ethN` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried creating a blank `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules` ?

since Udev v197, udev has implemented predictable network interface names, by creating a blank file in that path then rebooting, you should have your interface names back to what they were.

i answered a similar question at : `Creating eth0 with consistent network device naming`

Comment: This fixed two of my three network devices. Instead of a blank file, I created a link to /dev/null. I expect either approach would work.

Comment: Looks like this was changes around v210 that file has been removed from systemd if i'm reading this correctly: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/dfb08b058401d56c395f4f2d20ff214d31a277e5