# Renaming my wlan network interface

Tags: wifi, udev

I know this question is similar to "[Udev : renaming my network interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91085/udev-renaming-my-network-interface)", but I do not consider it a duplicate because my interface is not named via a udev rule, and none of the other answers in that question worked for me.

So I have one WiFi adapter on this laptop machine, and I would like to rename the interface from wlp5s0 to wlan0:

```
root@aj-laptop:/etc/udev/rules.d# iwconfig
wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

root@aj-laptop:/etc/udev/rules.d# ifconfig wlp5s0
wlp5s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:80:34:1f:d8:3f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

However, there are no rules for this interface in 70-persistent-net.rules or any of the other files in the /etc/udev/rules.d/ directory.

Is there any way that I can rename this interface?

Comment: There is a good explanation for Debian: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Choose a solution:

1. `ip link set wlp5s0 name wlan0` - not permanent
2. create yourself an udev rule file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` - permanent
3. add `net.ifnames=0` kernel parameter into grub.cfg - permanent, if
   your distro won't overwrite it.

Comment: I never knew you could rename an interface using the "ip" utility, worked great! I'll try the _net.ifnames=0_ boot parameter to make it permanent. Thanks!

Comment: solution `1.` while eventually generating a sane (memorizable) name, already requires one to go the length to lookup the "predictable name" (thanks systemd), which changes upon inserting usb dongle in a different port. solution `2` is a stub,  and solution `3` disables the systemd alias altogethe. Is there no way to keep the contorted `systemd` permanent name + and still have a sane alias like `wlan0`?

Comment: For convenience It's better to add #3 to /etc/default/grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX instead so it will always be effective for all linux boot options .

Answer (score 2):

On Linux Mint 18:

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

says in comment:

> This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
>   program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
>
> You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
>   line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

So, I suppose, just change the NAME key to your liking.

Comment: Yeah, mine has the same on the top. The problem is that there is only one line in that file, for the eth0 interface. I can't change a rule that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Gogeta70 Strange, I have both wlan and eth there. Nevermind, then.