# What is 'wlo1' ?

Tags: wifi, ifconfig

When I run the command *ifconfig* in the terminal, I get three results: *lo*, *virbr0*, *wlo1*.

- What is *wlo1*? Is it useful?

Comment: Presumably your wireless card. Add the output of `iwconfig` and `sudo lshw -C network` to the post, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wlo1` is a wireless network interface (NIC). You can use the command `iwlist scan` to scan the wireless NICs for available WiFi SSIDs.

#### Examples

`iw` is the preferred tool when querying WiFi devices. You can also use NetworkManager's CLI tool, `nmcli`, or if you're on an older version of Linux, use `iwlist`.

*iw*

```
$ iw dev wlan0 scan
BSS 15:cd:10:e4:26:39(on wlan0)
        TSF: 0 usec (0d, 00:00:00)
        freq: 2412
        beacon interval: 100 TUs
        capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime RadioMeasure (0x1431)
        signal: -8.00 dBm
        last seen: 0 ms ago
        SSID: bill_fi_the_science_wi
        Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0
        DS Parameter set: channel 1
        TIM: DTIM Count 0 DTIM Period 1 Bitmap Control 0x0 Bitmap[0] 0x0
        ERP: <no flags>
        ERP D4.0: <no flags>
        RSN:     * Version: 1
                 * Group cipher: CCMP
                 * Pairwise ciphers: CCMP
                 * Authentication suites: PSK
...
```

*iwlist (older cli)*

```
$ iwlist scan
enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enxfcde56ff0106  Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: C8:D7:79:50:D4:03
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"hermes"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000150d484187
                    Extra: Last beacon: 7724ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00066865726D6573
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A2C101FFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C332C101FFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3401000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0600E04C020160
```

#### References

- [Troubleshooting wifi connection on an HP Laptop on Ubuntu](https://blog.droidzone.in/2017/03/29/troubleshooting-wifi-connection-on-an-hp-laptop-on-ubuntu/)
- [Renaming my wlan network interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400893/renaming-my-wlan-network-interface)
- [iw man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iw)

Comment: BTW, `iwlist` etc. are the old tools, the newer tool is `iw`. Some features will only be accessible via `iw`.

Comment: @dirkt - ah thanks, didn't know that, I'll add an example of that too.