# What does 'wlo' stand for in NetworkManager device 'wlo1'?

Tags: linux, wifi, terminology

My wifi device gets the network device name `wlo1`.

Is `wlo` an acronym?

Wireless? Local?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453777/what-is-wlo1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the interface name according to the new "predictable" naming scheme as explained [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html).

In your case, `wl` means "Wireless LAN interface", and the `o` means "on-board".

Note that this corresponds to the `ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD` property which is not always used. You will therefore often find systems where WLAN interfaces are named `wlan0` or similar instead.