# How to cancel the kernel's rename of the Network interface?

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2, network-interface

I compiled the kernel of Linux 6.4.0 myself and used busybox to create a root file system. I customized my own Linux system and installed it on an embedded board with four network ports, which were connected using the **ax88772** chip.

I have a problem now: the network port name recognized by my system is similar to `enx000ec6942ec5`, which changes with the `MAC` address. However, I hope that the network port name is `eth`. I can also fix Ethernet port 1 to `eth0`, Ethernet port 2 to `eth1`, Ethernet port 3 to `eth2`, and Ethernet port 4 to `eth3`. I saw online that if I cancel the rename attribute of the kernel, it can be achieved, but I tried the following two methods and did not solve my problem.

**By the way, my customized system only changed `M` or `Y` in Linux `menuconfig` to `N` without modifying the kernel source code.**

1. Turn it off in `grub.cfg`, but it has no effect;

   ```
   set default=0
   set timeout=4

   set root=(hd0,gpt3)

   menuentry "GNU/Linux, Dobot-6.4.0-rt" {
     linux /bzImage rw root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 noprompt

     initrd /initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8
     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
   }
   ```
2. [In this way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400893/renaming-my-wlan-network-interface), the MAC needs to be fixed, but I need to use it for multiple devices, and the MAC is not fixed.

May I ask if there is any other way?

Comment: What do you use to configure network? As you saw: udev is one way to link a name to a specific device on kernel. Some network configuration tools have it implemented directly (e.g. systemd networkd ).

Comment: (don't know where you've got `biosdevname` from, but it simply doesn't apply to you.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Thank you for your answer, which made me realize the difference between them, but this is not the answer to my question. I just hope my nic can be fixed as ethX.

Comment: It does answer your question, because it explains which  kernel argument to use instead (as literally said in the title.)

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to use the `biosdevname` parameter if you're not using Dell's old network interface renamer script. (you probably aren't.)

You can use the `net.ifnames` directive of udev/systemd that can be used to stop renaming.

But I'm *very* worried that you're hurting yourself here: You say "I hope it's fixed `ethX`", indicating that you expect more than one ethernet interface to be present (which you wouldn't have to call `ethX`, but simply `eth0`). And that's **EXACTLY** the case where you *need* the so-called "predicable interface names": these `X` in `ethX` are assigned by *detection order*. And that can be, and often is, totally random. So, what was `eth0` this boot might be `eth1` next boot. That's why the renaming was invented!

You probably hence *do not want to disable renaming(!)*, because the un-renamed `ethX` names are unreliable. Instead, you'd use `net.ifname-policy=onboard,path,slot` to make the name be the same regardless of MAC. Simply don't use the ancient `ethX` convention! (it *really* wasn't a great idea to begin with, since computers can have multiple network cards connected in various ways. This scheme is from a time where computers did not usually have multiple interfaces, or multiple buses to which to connect cards, or PCI express. Basically, this scheme was obsolete for PCs by 1996, technologically, with the advent of USB! Twenty years ago, PCI express hit the PC market, and the `ethX` scheme became a real problem, making it hard to set up Linux correctly. So, "we" solved that, by using renaming that isn't based on the random order of detection, but on fixed characteristics. For some reason, it still haunts tutorials, guides and thus is a common misconception underlying software.)

Comment: Yes, I am not Dell's hardware.

Comment: … so, read the rest of my answer.

Comment: Forgive me for not having as much knowledge as you. Let me summarize, do you mean to let me put `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifname-policy=onboard,path,slot"`  in `grub.cfg`？My root file system is created by `busybox`, and I am not very familiar with udev/systemd. I hope to receive further guidance.

Comment: ah! but the renaming is done by something. Probably udev!