# Linux Guest in VMware Workstation: How to map NIC in Guest OS to different VMnet?

Tags: vmware-workstation

**Update**

Please take note that this question has nothing to do with [Renaming my wlan network interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400893/renaming-my-wlan-network-interface)

That question doesn't have anything to do with **VMware Workstation**

**My Question is related to Linux Guest OS inside VMware Workstation**

I have Linux installed in VMware Workstation with 3 network interfaces.

To make it easier to read, I have assigned 3rd octet of the IP Address based on VMnet ID.

```
VMnet1 - 172.31.1.0/24
VMnet2 - 172.31.2.0/24
VMnet3 - 172.31.3.0/24
```

The setting of VMware Virtual Network Editor is as follows:

[image: Virtual Network Editor]

Virtual Machine Settings

[image]

DHCP is used in this setup.

When I run `ifconfig`, I found that

```
eth0 assigned to VMnet2 network
eth1 assigned to VMnet3 network
eth2 assigned to VMnet1 network
```

I'm not sure why VMware assign it this way.

```
user@linux:~$ ifconfig | grep ad
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:AA:AA:A0  
          inet addr:172.31.2.23  Bcast:172.31.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:AA:AA:A1
          inet addr:172.31.3.22  Bcast:172.31.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:AA:AA:A2  
          inet addr:172.31.1.24  Bcast:172.31.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

user@linux:~$
```

Is it possible to change it?

I would like to get something like this ...

```
eth1 assigned to VMnet1 network
eth2 assigned to VMnet2 network
eth0 assigned to VMnet3 network
```

Comment: There is no relation between the number of the "Network Adapter" in VMWare and the number of eth interface inside the virtual machine. You can use udev rules to give custom names to your interfaces, using mac addresses to recognize them. I voted to close this question as a duplicate of many others.

Comment: Erkk .. there is ... if you set 5 "Network Adapter" interfaces in VMWare , then you'll get 5 interfaces as well ... eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3, eth4.

Are you sure you're using VMware Workstation and Linux?

Comment: the wlan issue not related to this at all ...

Comment: Another question on the same issue: [Udev : renaming my network interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91085/udev-renaming-my-network-interface)

Comment: Again, doesn't appear related.

Comment: @Sabrina _SO ... it isn't very welcoming._ Your conception of voting (here, at SO/SE) appears misguided. Voting without comment or justification is perfectly acceptable here. Votes (up or down) just reflect whether the voter finds the post particularly useful or not. Your implicit expectation that a downvote must be accompanied by a suggestion for improvement has simply no foundation. You should not take votes as something personal.

Comment: @Sabrina You have to resort to udev in any case (but I see that the "duplicate" does not answer your question). A good read on udev rule writing is http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html (N.B. `udevinfo` became `udevadm info`) - the paragraph _Network interfaces_ comes very close to what you asked for. Thus you only need to create a simple rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` or `/lib/udev/rules.d/` (as described in `udev(7)`) where you assign interface names based on the MAC address. (Needless to say they need to be static for this stunt to work.)

Comment: @Sabrina See also https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Udev#Usage for a more up-to-date advice.