# Changing MAC address in udev and KERNEL=="eth*"

Tags: network-interface, udev

I have a server with ubuntu on it and everything work fine.
All network interfaces are working.

I decide to move the drive to a new server and it boots to the OS without issue.
The network interfaces aren't working due to he different network card.
So `70-persistent-net.rules`  and change the `ATTR{address}==` with the new MAC addresses and reboot the server.

After, reboot the network interfaces are still not working.
So I find this solution:
[Udev : renaming my network interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91085/udev-renaming-my-network-interface)

It tells me to delete the `KERNEL=="eth*"` part.
I do that, reboot and the network works perfectly.

So my question is, Why?

What is this `KERNEL` attribute and why does it solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be two network interfaces with the same name, ever. So if `udev` will need to swap e.g. `eth1` to `eth2` and vice versa, it will first rename one of the NICs to `rename`, possibly with a unique string added, and then will do another pass.

But on the second pass, the `KERNEL=="eth*"` will no longer match the NIC, because its name is now `rename`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That makes a lot of sense.
I thought my issue was similar but I guess not.

For me I'm moving my drives to a new server, the only config I'm changing in udev is the MAC addresses to match the new server's network card.
And I can only get the interfaces up when removing the KERNEL=="eth*"